# SimpleDateFormat Exception on setting lenient to false

Tags: java, datetime, formatting

Why is this code throwing exception of unparseable date?

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.000Z'");
f.setLenient(false);
String dateStr = "2012-03-11T02:46:01.000Z";
f.parse(dateStr);
```

It works fine when lenient is true. It strangely works for input date '**2012-03-01T02:46:01.000Z**' even with lenient as false. 
Default timezone being used : PST

Comment: Worked for using your code, got `Sun Mar 11 02:46:01 GMT 2012` back from the date, and it seems to work with other strings.

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: It fails for me in the described way using both 1.6.0_37 and 1.7.0_04.

Comment: Now I know the problem, I added my default timezone in question for clarity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because that time does not exist in your default time zone—it was daylight savings time change day, and time jumped from 2:00 a.m. to 3:00 a.m., so there was no 2:46 that morning. :P

Since you’re parsing UTC, set the `SimpleDateFormat` instance time zone to UTC like so:

```
f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

and your problem will go away.