# Spring Batch - unable to parse date with correct format

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-batch

In spring batch I'm loading csv file where I'm also parsing dates.
Everything seems to be working fine except for one single row where I get exception

`Unparseable date: "2014-03-09 02:07:07", format: [yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss]`

I've double checked my input file and there are no special/invisible characters in this failed row.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unparseable date: "2014-03-09 02:07:07", format: [yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DefaultFieldSet.parseDate(DefaultFieldSet.java:778)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DefaultFieldSet.readDate(DefaultFieldSet.java:595)
```

Thanks for help!

---

**EDIT**

> When I change hour in date from **02** to something else (e.g. '2014-03-09 **03**:07:07'), it works. When I then change it manually back to **02** it fails again. How can this be possible? Changing other elements of date does not help. Only changing hour.
>
> I only experience this on our unix server with America/New_York timezone. From my local machine everything is working. JDK version on both are identical.

Comment: can you post your code snippet too?

Comment: its spring batch defaultfieldset I use. Not much code I can post.

Comment: oh.. might be a locale issue.. can you check what locale its using..

Comment: It is somehow related to locale. I've debugged this code and found exception - `HOUR_OF_DAY: 2 -> 3`. Locale on our unix server is `en_US` what is strange is that at this exact date in 2014 was start of daylight saving. So basically time 02:07:07 does not exist. I currently dont know how to fix this.

Comment: did you check http://stackoverflow.com/a/9085220/62201 ?

Comment: I've figured it out. It was interesting issue :)

Answer (score 1):

It was caused by combination of `TimeZone` settings, daylight saving and `SimpleDateFormat.lenient` property.

Our linux host has `America/New_York` timezone.

Date for which I was getting error is 9-MAR-2014 @ 2:07:07 am
which is exact date and time when in NYK timezone time shifts [1 hour forward](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa/new-york?year=2014) - daylight saving (from 2am to 3am).

Normally when SimpleDateFormat converts such date it [automatically changes it to 3am](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574109/simpledateformat-exception-on-setting-lenient-to-false). Setting `lenient` property to `false` (default value for is `true`) prevents this and throws exception - `HOUR_OF_DAY: 2 -> 3`.

This exception is consumed in process and at the end we get only `IllegalArgumentException` with `Unparseable date: "2014-03-09 02:07:07", format: [yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss]` message.

Here I'm using spring-boot `DefaultFieldSet` which has implementation where it is specifically setting `lenient` to `false`.

```
/* ... some other code ... */
private DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DEFAULT_DATE_PATTERN);
{
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);
}

/* ... some other code ... */

@Override
public Date readDate(int index, String pattern) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    sdf.setLenient(false);
    return parseDate(readAndTrim(index), sdf);
}
/* ... some other code ... */
```

As we are not doing any manipulation with dates in our code, I simply fixed it with changing default timezone to UTC.

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Other valid approach would be to write custom implementation of `FieldSet`.